# jQuery function is unintenionally altering text content of links and affecting CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having very strange issues with some jQuery I've written, it seems to be altering the text content of links, and outputting a strange garbled mess. Reloading the page after seeing this happen results in everything rendering as expected. In addition, there are strange CSS issues that occur at the same time, with elements overflowing past their intended boundaries, which is also fixed on a refresh.

Here's a link to a screenshot of the issue. Red arrows point to the strange garbled link text, yellow arrows point to improper CSS. Inspecting the source of any of these elements will show the proper and intended CSS, as well as the correct text within the  tags, even though neither is reflected in the page.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3p0P.png]

This might be a caching issue, as I can force the issue to happen when doing a ctrl+f5 refresh, and then after that hitting just f5 again displays the page as intended.

Here's the only code on my site affecting these links/their parent elements in any way

```
$.fn.linkHighlight = function() {
  // highlight links in the sidebar when hovering in the article, and vice-versa

  var selectorText = ".post-content a, .sidebar-wrap a";
  $(selectorText).mouseenter(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(selectorText).each(function(){
      if( $(this).attr("href") == $this.attr("href") ) {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
      }
    });
  });
  $(selectorText).mouseleave(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(selectorText).each(function(){
      if( $(this).attr("href") == $this.attr("href") ) {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
      }
    });
  });
};
```

This function is being called in a standard `$(document).ready(function({}));`

Any help would be appreciated! If you want to see it happen on a live site, the screenshot above was taken from http://mikedettmer.com/projects/viewportunitpatch/

Comment: It works fine for me in my browser: Chrome on Windows 7!

Comment: Can you provide your fiddle please.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't considered that is might be an OS issue. I'm running Chrome on Windows 10 and can reliably duplicate the issue. I can also reliably duplicate it on Chrome for Android when I clear my cache there.

I can try to set it up in a fiddle, but I doubt that it will be duplicated there. Seems very specific to my live site's setup.